# webpack loader error with OpenLayer after migrating angular from v14 to v15 with Nx

Tags: webpack, openlayers, css-loader, angular15, angular14upgrade

I have migrated my app from Angular 14 to 15 using Nx (nx migrate). Npm i works well but then I have several errors when trying to nx serve.

`Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:24)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| /* SEARCH ENGINE */
|

> [id^="GPsearchEngine-"] {
> |   top: 8px;
> |   left: 46px;`

It looks like the issue occurs because of OpenLayer, the css files.

I tried to reinstall the style loader and css loader but nothing works so far.

Do you have any idea what is going wrong ?

Comment: Could you share which package do you use for OpenLayer?

Comment: "geoportal-extensions-openlayers": "^3.2.8", 
 "ol": "6.9.0",